# Is it right to place events on Business hours in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

- when event drag from resource and drop on Business hours it's allow to be on gray area (Business hours). Is it right?
- When event drag to change time slot from calendrer it's still allow to place on business hours

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: "UTC",
    initialView: "resourceTimelineDay",
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next",
      center: "title",
      right: "resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth"
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: "Rooms",
    businessHours: {
      // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
      daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4], // Monday - Thursday

      startTime: "12:00", // a start time (10am in this example)
      endTime: "18:00" // an end time (6pm in this example)
    },
    resources: [
      { id: "a", title: "Resource A" },
      { id: "b", title: "Resource B" }
    ],
    events: [
      { title: "Event 2", start: "2023-11-10", resourceId: "a" },
      { title: "Event 3", start: "2023-11-10", resourceId: "b" }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='calendar'></div>
    <link href='fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src='fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>
```

Kindly help me to share your conclusion and answers

Comment: If you need help from the Stackoverflow community you **must** provide a [mre] of your issue _here_ in _this_ question, not on some other post on another site (even if it's another Stackexchange site). Then the question is a) easier to understand and b) not subject to changes or removal of the other post in the future. See also [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Anyway your provided link (https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410) doesn't appear to contain anything related to fullCalendar, unless I missed it.

Comment: In regards to your actual question, you can set https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventConstraint and/or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAllow to control where events can be dragged to. It's unclear what, if anything, you've researched or attempted so far. The documentation has quite a lot of detail. Again see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for editing, but the code snippet doesn't run. Please add the fullcalendar script link to it. The cloudflare one is clearly irrelevant. In future if you add a code snippet, please make sure it's actually usable before submitting it (otherwise it somewhat defeats the point of using the Snippet feature).

Comment: And please take note of my point above, about eventConstraint. That should already solve your issue.

Comment: What does "Business hours" do for us more than just show a gray area to the user?

Comment: That depends on how you use it. It can be used to help impose restrictions on where events can be placed, for example. Have you read the documentation I provided yet?